# iOS - Java - Issue with Post that having unicode

Tags: java, mysql, ios, web-services, unicode

Our iOS app is working with the Webservices of JAVA and saving data to MYSQL DB.

Now the Problem is, When ever data having UNICODES from IOS is Sent to Webservices, it is not saving the Data in DB. In place of unicodes it stores "?".

We checked DB and made sure that Collection of DB is set to UTF-8 default.And if We manually stores those Character via any IDE then it is displaying there.

We Checked that whether unicodes are reaching to WebServices or not.

Then we just made an Application on JAVA to just fire a query to insert a Row with Data having UNICODE in it. But then also JAVA App can not insert that hardCoded String into DB.

Comment: Could you add the code that does the actual insert, and how you're connecting to the database?

Comment: +1 for You. I just checked the Connection string and i found that i missed to specify UTF-8 in to this. You should post answer.

Comment: But now another issue is there. Unicodes sent to JAVA is \U0050 this raising invalid escape sequence during json parsing due to \U. it needs \u